# секундомер со временем,которое пользователь находится на сайте JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как сделать такой секундомер что бы при наведении мыши он приостанавливался,а если мышь убрать то считал с того же момента на котором остановился,и при нажатии esc обнулялся. Очень много уже перечитал но такого как мне нужно так и не нашел =( Буду очень признателен за помощь !!!

Answer (score 4):

Вот так? Обнуление оставил Вам на закуску.

Это основа основ любой анимации, считать сколько времени прошло

```js
let fromTime = new Date().getTime();
let mouseoverTime;
let div = document.querySelector('div')
div.addEventListener('mouseover', () => mouseoverTime = new Date().getTime());
div.addEventListener('mouseout', () => mouseoverTime = null);

animate();

function animate() {
  let time = new Date().getTime();
  if (mouseoverTime) {
     fromTime += time - mouseoverTime;
     mouseoverTime = time;
  }
  div.innerHTML = (time - fromTime)/1000;
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}
```

```css
div{
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  border: solid black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

РS: Если надо чтобы таймер тикал в фоне(на неактивной вкладке) то `requestAnimationFrame` нужно заменить на `setTimeout`